# Where to find a network connection’s last used date/time?

Tags: linux, networking

In the Linux Network Manager Connection Editor there is a column called "Last Used" that approximates how long ago a connection was last made. In Fedora, where can I find the actual exact timestamp of when the network connection was last used?

I've looked in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, `/etc/NetworkManager/` , and `/var/lib/NetworkManager` but I can't find a date time entry anywhere. The connection editor would have to be calculating how long ago it was last used from a log somewhere wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps are in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/timestamps`:

```
[timestamps]
9b6da6f6-f266-4aae-a742-072053f70a1d=1467272295
288ec246-6a27-3d69-827d-fc9dd8399344=1469766848
...
```

That number on the right is a [Unix epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in seconds:

```
$ date -d @1469766848
Fri Jul 29 04:34:08 UTC 2016
```

Though you shouldn't try to parse the file directly (internal formats might change in the future) – instead, the same information can be obtained via D-Bus or nmcli:

```
$ nmcli con show 288ec246-6a27-3d69-827d-fc9dd8399344 | grep time
connection.timestamp:                   1469766848
```